# check if physical auto-negotiation is ongoing

Tags: linux, ethernet

Is there any way in Linux to see if an ethernet auto-negotiation is ongoing or has already terminated?

For instance, I see that in my network it takes a 1Gb interface 3 to 4 seconds to correctly update its link status after I set its administrative status to "up".

For now I see that `/sys/class/net/$eth/speed` yields `invalid argument` if the interface is down, `-1` if a negotiation is ongoing and the negotiated speed value once the negotiation is done. This might be a first approximation for a solution. Anything more precise than this?

On a side note, `/sys/class/net/$eth/operstate` is `down` both when `speed` is `-1` and when it is `invalid value`, so I can't use it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like we can get what you need with "ethtool" and "perf".

From the ethtool man page:

> -r --negotiate
>
> Restarts auto-negotiation on the specified Ethernet device, if auto-negotiation is enabled.

To learn more about the perf command, and there is much to know, check out Brendan Gregg's website:
http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html

We can do a perf record of the ethtool renegotiation:

`# perf record ethtool -r <interface>`

And then display the report

`# perf report --stdio`

On my virtual machine which is using the Intel e1000 driver, I get these results for the report... your results may vary.

```
# Overhead  Command      Shared Object                                 Symbol
# ........  .......  .................  .....................................
#
    17.39%  ethtool  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] e1000_raise_ee_clk.isra.7
    13.04%  ethtool  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] __lock_text_start
    13.04%  ethtool  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] delay_tsc
    13.04%  ethtool  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] e1000_shift_in_ee_bits
     8.70%  ethtool  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] e1000_lower_ee_clk.isra.8
     4.35%  ethtool  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] e1000_acquire_eeprom
     4.35%  ethtool  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] e1000_configure_rx
     4.35%  ethtool  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] e1000_init_hw
     4.35%  ethtool  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] e1000_release_eeprom
     4.35%  ethtool  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] e1000_standby_eeprom
     4.35%  ethtool  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] finish_task_switch
     4.35%  ethtool  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] kmem_cache_free
     4.35%  ethtool  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] native_read_tsc
```